# How to log output of sass --watch?

Tags: bash, sass

I run

```
sass --watch /app/sass:/app/css
```

inside a Docker container and want to log everything it outputs to the file

```
/tmp/sass.log
```

because i want to monitor it, in case of an error.

My current solution is to start the watch command using the following

```
sass --watch /app/sass:/app/css | echo /tmp/sass.log
```

but it doesn't log the output, unfortunately.

Help would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the re-direction operator, `>` for writing to a file

```
sass --watch /app/scss:/app/css > /tmp/sass.log
```

(or) in case you want to monitor on screen via `stdout` and also want the logs to written to a file you can use `tee` command as

```
sass --watch /app/scss:/app/css | tee /tmp/sass.log
```

Comment: Thanks! That small change did it!